# OnClick Method Does Not Update TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, onclicklistener, buttonclick

Every time I click on:

```
 assist_update_btn
```

I the textview should be update with text from a different string value however it never appears to do anything when I click assist_update_btn.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

SOURCE:

```
public class UpdateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public static ArrayList<String> NameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> nameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ApnArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmscArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsportArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsproxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> portArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> proxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ImageView mProgressImageview1;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview2;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview3;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview4;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview5;
    public static int count;
    AlertDialog mErrorAlert = null;
    int version;
    public static int TotalSteps = 8;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "STDataSettings";
    private Button mUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistInstrButton = null;
    private TextView mReadAgainButton = null;
    private int mInstructionNumber = 0;
    AlertDialog mConfirmAlert = null;
    public static InputStream stream = null;
    public static XmlParserHandlerFinal handler;
    private NetworkTask task;
    private AnimationDrawable loadingAnimation;
    private static final String TAG = "UpdateActivity";
    Context ctx;
    private Button assist_update_btn = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int networkType = tm.getNetworkType();
        int phoneType = tm.getPhoneType();
        handler = new XmlParserHandlerFinal();
        int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (phoneType == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA
                || (phoneType != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE)) {
            // If the phone type is CDMA or
            // the phone phone type is not GSM and the network type is none of
            // the network types indicated in the statement
            // Display incompatibility message
            showAlert(getString(R.string.incomp_sm_dialog));
            // Network type is looked because some tablets have no phone type.
            // We rely on network type in such cases
        } else if (!(tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                || (tm.getSimOperator())
                .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo)) || (tm
                        .getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att)))) {
            // if SIM is present and is NOT a T-Mo network SIM,
            // display Error message alert indicating to use SM SIM
            showAlert(getString(R.string.insert_sm_dialog));
        }// No SIM or SIM with T-Mo MNC MCC present
        else if (version < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            // Initial UI setup for versions lower than ICS
            setContentView(R.layout.update);
            mUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_button);

            mUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else {// ICS and up

            // task.execute();

            if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                    .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
                task = new NetworkTask();
                task.execute("");
                // Device has T-Mo network SIM card MCC and MNC correctly
                // populated
                // Reduce number of steps to 6
                TotalSteps = 6;
            }

        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.equals(assist_update_btn)) {
            // Update button for versions lower than ICS is selected
            // setContentView(R.layout.updating);
            onClickMethod(v);

            Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        //  finish();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.assist_update_btn) {

            // Update button for ICS and up is selected
            // Get the TextView in the Assist Update UI
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            String text = "";
            CharSequence styledText = text;
            switch (mInstructionNumber) {
            case 0:
                // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
                // 2nd set of instructions
                text = String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                        TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 1:
                text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 2:
                // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

                setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
                String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                        getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
                TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
                assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
                mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
                mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
                mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        } else if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {
            // "LET'S DO THIS" Button in final instructions screen for ICS and
            // up is selected
            // Create ConfigActivity Intent
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
            // Invoke ConfigActivity Intent to start the assisted update
            startActivity(i);
            //finish();
        } else if (v == mReadAgainButton) {
            // go back to 1st set of instructions if read again is selected
            mInstructionNumber = 0;
            setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);
            String assistUpdate = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_cta2);
            CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdate);
            TextView assistText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            assistText.setText(styledText);
            mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
            mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void onClickMethod(View v) {
        mUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.drawable.btn_update_active_hdpi);

    }

    private void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                UpdateActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        mConfirmAlert = builder.create();
        mConfirmAlert.show();
    }
    // AsyncTask to call web service
             class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, InputStream> {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {

                    super.onPreExecute();
                }

                @Override
                protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {

                    try {
                        // saving the response in InputStream
                        stream = getQueryResults("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31771876/GetPhoneSettings-ST-rsp-eng.xml");
                    //  stream = new BufferedInputStream(https.getInputStream());
                               DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(stream);
                                   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                                 String strLine; 
                                   while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) { // Print the content on the console
                                       System.out.println (strLine); 
                                   System.out.println (strLine); 
                                         in.close();
                                   }


                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SAXException e) {

                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // The code below plays a Simple Promo animation

                    for (int incr = 0; incr < 2; incr++) {
                        // Sleep for 1/2 second
                        // Invoke UI to change updating text to show 1 dot
                        // And Increasing the level to reduce the amount of clipping and
                        // slowly reveals the hand image
                        publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                                R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                                R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                        }
                        publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                                R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                                R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                        }
                        publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                                R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                                R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                        }
                        publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                                R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                                R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                        }
                        publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                                R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                                R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full);

                        // Sleep for 1/2 second
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                        }
                    }
                    return stream;
                }
                    /*
                     * Sends a query to server and gets back the parsed results in a bundle
                     * urlQueryString - URL for calling the webservice
                     */
                    protected synchronized InputStream getQueryResults(String urlQueryString)
                            throws IOException, SAXException, SSLException,
                            SocketTimeoutException, Exception {
                        // HttpsURLConnection https = null;


                        HttpsURLConnection https = null;
                        String uri = urlQueryString;

                        URL urlo = new URL(uri);

                        try {
                            https = (HttpsURLConnection) urlo.openConnection();
                            https.setConnectTimeout(20000); // 20 second timeout
                            https.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                            if ("gzip".equals(https.getContentEncoding())) {
                                stream = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
                            } else
                                stream = https.getInputStream();

                        } catch (SSLException e) {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } finally {
                            // https.disconnect();
                        }

                        return stream;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

                        // Call function to update image view

                        setProgressImgView(progress[0], progress[1], progress[2], progress[3], progress[4]);

                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream stream) {
                        super.onPostExecute(stream);
            // This method is called to parse the response and save the ArrayLists
                        success();
                        assistUpdate();
                        //setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);

                    }

                }

                private void assistUpdate() {
                    // Displaying final layout after pre-ICS automatic settings update
                    setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);
                    assist_update_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
                    assist_update_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

                }

                private void setProgressImgView(Integer imageViewId1, Integer imageViewId2, Integer imageViewId3, Integer imageViewId4, Integer imageViewId5) {
                    // update image view with the updating dots
                    // Reset view layout in case orientation while updating
                    setContentView(R.layout.updating);

                    mProgressImageview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty1);
                    mProgressImageview1.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId1);
                    mProgressImageview2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty2);
                    mProgressImageview1.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId2);
                    mProgressImageview3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty3);
                    mProgressImageview1.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId3);
                    mProgressImageview4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty4);
                    mProgressImageview1.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId4);
                    mProgressImageview5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty5);
                    mProgressImageview1.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId5);

                }

                @Override
                protected void onRestart() {
                    super.onRestart();

                    if (mErrorAlert != null)
                        mErrorAlert.dismiss();
                }


                public void success() {

                    // to parse the response
                    try {
                        handler.getQueryResponse(stream);

                    } catch (SAXException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // to set method to save the ArryaLists from the parser
                    setArrayList();
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    //finish();

                }
                // method to save the ArrayLists from parser
                public static void setArrayList() {
                    nameArr = handler.getnameArr();
                    ApnArr = handler.getApnArr();
                    mmscArr = handler.getMMSCArr();
                    mmsproxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();
                    mmsportArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
                    proxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();
                    portArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
                    count = handler.getCount();
                    //System.out.println("testing123");


                    for(int i = 0; i < nameArr.size()-1; i++){
                        System.out.println(nameArr.get(i));
                    }


                    for(int i = 0; i < ApnArr.size()-1; i++){
                        System.out.println(ApnArr.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you show how you set up your button listener. also its is better to move the initialization of textview outside onClick. and you also calling finish

Comment: I updated my source above to show it

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.assist_update_btn) {
        //Your code
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.assist_instr_btn) {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my source to follow the method you suggested (source shown above) clicking  assist_instr_btn still does nothing

Comment: @user2700431 Remove this line `setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);` which is below `assistUpdate();` in your `onPostExecute()` method

Comment: Done. Updated source above. Still no change in text when clicking assist_update_btn

Comment: Try setting the listener for `onClick` in your `layout xml` file. And check if you get the callback from there. Your code seems to be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

`if (v == assist_update_btn)`

when you should be using

`if (v.equals(assist_update_btn))`.

I personally think it's more robust to create a separate OnClickListener for each button instead of handling all buttons with one method.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == assist_update_btn) {
```

to:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.assist_update_btn) {
```

and your problem should be long gone.

Comment: I updated my source above to implement the method suggested and clicking the button still does nothing (text does not appear to change)

Comment: @user2700431 are you sure this condition works `if (result.equals("success")) {
            assistUpdate();
            //completeUpdate();
        }`

Comment: @user2700431 you have `setContentView` twice. you certainly need to rethink your design. Also does your activity implement OnClickListener?

Comment: I need to have two seperate flows for pre ICS devices - and devices running ICS and later - this is why some of the source appears to be duplicated at times. ...and yes  - I am implementing OnClickListener

Comment: @user2700431 your code is so confusing. Did you try to debug does it actually enter onClick method. could you log some info where you update textview and check if the control actually enters the block.

Comment: I just ran a debug session with a breakpoint at  public void onClick(View v) {
     if (v.equals(assist_update_btn)) {


...and it appears it is never reaching it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize TextView in `assistUpdate()`. Declare `tv` as a class member.

```
   @Override // missing override annotation    
   public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.assist_update_btn :
              // do something. assist_update_btn click code here
        break;
        case R.id.mAssistInstrButton :
             // do domething . mAssistInstrButton click code here
        break;
    }
```

I see you have `setContenView` twice for the same activitty. I don't think its necessary.

Edit :

You have a for loop in `doInbackground()` you also call `publishProgress` more than once and you have multiple try catch block.

```
   publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                            R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                    }
```

I am confused as to what your doing. But i strongly suggest you to rethink your design.

Comment: The first time is for pre ICS devices only (it needs to be there - there is a different flow for pre ICS devices in this project)